# peer getting crash : runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode

after a long time my peer getting crash every time whenever i am facing below error
hf version : 1.4.2
go version go1.12.6 linux/amd64
ubuntu TLS 16.04

```
free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:         257611       11125      151795        2657       94689      241076
Swap:           976           0         976
```

**Peer Logs**

```
2019-11-28 17:29:53.646 UTC [deliveryClient] try -> WARN de55 Got error: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing , at 1 attempt. Retrying in 1s
2019-11-28 17:29:53.829 UTC [deliveryClient] try -> WARN de56 Got error: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing , at 1 attempt. Retrying in 1s
2019-11-28 17:29:55.826 UTC [deliveryClient] try -> WARN de57 Got error: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing , at 1 attempt. Retrying in 1s
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0xaed020]

goroutine 136 [running]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/gossip.(*SecretEnvelope).InternalEndpoint(0x0, 0x40c4c3, 0x7f849226ddc8)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/gossip/extensions.go:480 +0x40
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/discovery.newAliveMsgStore.func4(0x1243280, 0xc00254ab10)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/discovery/discovery_impl.go:1032 +0xfd
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/gossip/msgstore.(*messageStoreImpl).expireMessages(0xc002656180)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/gossip/msgstore/msgs.go:212 +0x34c
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/gossip/msgstore.(*messageStoreImpl).expirationRoutine(0xc002656180)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/gossip/msgstore/msgs.go:253 +0x141
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/gossip/msgstore.NewMessageStoreExpirable
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/gossip/msgstore/msgs.go:53 +0xb2
```

**chaincode logs**

```
2019/11/27 10:04:13 This complaintno already exists: 1709157484903969657
2019-11-28 17:44:50.198 UTC [shim] chatWithPeer -> ERRO 001 Received error from server, ending chaincode stream: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing
receive failed
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim.chatWithPeer
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim/chaincode.go:362
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim.Start
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim/chaincode.go:156
main.main
    /chaincode/input/src/github.com/chaincode/complaints/complaintchaincode.go:134
runtime.main
    /opt/go/src/runtime/proc.go:201
runtime.goexit
    /opt/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1333
2019/11/28 17:44:50 Error starting Complaint chaincode: receive failed: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing
```

i am facing this error for a long time but not able to debug it.

Comment: There is a bug in the peer 1.4.2, try to upgrade to 1.4.4 which is latest and try it

Answer (score 1):

You are experiencing a bug that was introduced in 1.4.2 and was [fixed](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/commit/c2353afb9b0ee75e4f2d6051e75677b038297d8e) in 1.4.3

Answer (score 0):

May be many reasons, but I have experienced some similar poltergeists that got solved by upgrading the docker version (and restarting the docker service, of course).